# Advanced urn problem

Tags: probability, stochastic-calculus, estimation

Imagine there are two urns — urn A and urn B. Urn A contains 3 blue balls and 7 red balls. Urn B contains 7 blue balls and 3 red balls. Balls are now randomly drawn from one of these urns where the drawn ball is always placed back into the same urn. Twelve such random draws yielded 8 red balls and 4 blue balls. What do you estimate the probability that the balls were drawn from urn A?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:  Can you calculate the probability that twelve draws from $A$ gave that result?  Similarly for draws from $B$?  Then the probability you want is the first divided by the sum.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I already tried this approach but was not sure because the result was a very high probability: 0.3^4*0.7^8 / (0.3^4*0.7^8 + 0.7^4*0.3^8) = 0.9674

Comment: Yes, it should be very high.  The proportion of the draws is higher in reds and A is higher in reds.  The chance you are drawing out of B is small.  I didn't run the numbers.

Comment: Ok nice. Thank you very much, Ross! Great to get help so fast!! :-)